# USPTO bulkdata download stalls for some files

Tags: uspto, bulk-download

When downloading bulk data from the USPTO site some downloads work fine, but others (around a dozen so far) stop downloading at the same point every attempt.

Example:

https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data/patent/application/redbook/fulltext/2003/pa030306.zip

This file consistently stops downloading around 78.5 MB out of 86.1 MB total. We have tried this download from multiple systems and from multiple countries on different internet connections.

Is this a known issue that others have experienced with the bulk dataset? Is there a work around that does not involve going to another source?